# Search by Hyphen

Tags: posts, wp-query

I'm currently running Wordpress on version **4.6.1** and I'm attempting to search for posts that contains the character `-` (hyphen). However, the search parameter is taking my hyphen for a negation.

From the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) documentation:

> Prepending a term with a hyphen will exclude posts matching that term. Eg, 'pillow -sofa' will return posts containing 'pillow' but not 'sofa' (available since Version 4.4).

Here's my query:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    's' => '-',
    'posts_per_page' => 36
));
```

I've tried to escape the hyphen by doing:

```
's' => '\-'
```

However, the result stays the same (`var_dump($query->request)`):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE
    1=1
    AND (((wp_posts.post_title NOT LIKE '%%')
    AND (wp_posts.post_excerpt NOT LIKE '%%')
    AND (wp_posts.post_content NOT LIKE '%%')))
    AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')
    AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation')
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled')
ORDER BY
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 36
```

Comment: very good and real question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to modify the *exclusion prefix* through the [`wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix/) filter that's supported in WP 4.7+.
See ticket [#38099](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38099).

Here's an example how we can change it from `-` to e.g. `!`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix', function( $prefix )
{
    return '!'; // adjust to your needs (default is -)
} );
```

where we would use `!apple` instead of `-apple` to exclude `apple` from the search results. Then you can search by `-`.

It looks like the exclusion prefix must be a single character (or empty to disable this feature), because of this [check in the core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/16371b99d8e5111dcc83b8961b4d68681e82d25e/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1335-L1344):

```
// If there is an $exclusion_prefix, terms prefixed with it should be excluded.
$exclude = $exclusion_prefix && ( $exclusion_prefix === substr( $term, 0, 1 ) );
if ( $exclude ) {
    $like_op  = 'NOT LIKE';
    $andor_op = 'AND';
    $term     = substr( $term, 1 );
} else {
    $like_op  = 'LIKE';
    $andor_op = 'OR';
}
```

Otherwise it sounds like a **bug**, not to be able to search only for the term exclusion prefix.

I wonder if it would be better to add an extra `$exclusion_prefix !== $term` check to support that:

```
$exclude = $exclusion_prefix 
    && $exclusion_prefix !== $term 
    && ( $exclusion_prefix === mb_substr( $term, 0, 1 ) );
if ( $exclude ) {
    $like_op  = 'NOT LIKE';
    $andor_op = 'AND';
    $term     = mb_substr( $term, 1 );
} else {
    $like_op  = 'LIKE';
    $andor_op = 'OR';
}
```

where we would also use `mb_substr()` instead of `substr()` for a wider char support for the exclusion prefix.

I guess I should just create ticket for this ...

Comment: https://wpseek.com/hook/wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix/

Comment: `mb_substr`, in PHP < 7 that function needs a treatment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953248/php-mb-substr-not-working-correctly.

Comment: thanks @prosti, I guess `get_option( 'blog_charset' )` could be an option for that, The `mb_substr()` is actually used in core in few places without the encoding argument, e.g. [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/16371b99d8e5111dcc83b8961b4d68681e82d25e/wp-includes/user.php#L1478) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/16371b99d8e5111dcc83b8961b4d68681e82d25e/wp-includes/formatting.php#L4518).  For setups without `mb_substr` and `mb_strlen()`,  WordPress ships with fallbacks with the same function names in `/wp-includes/compat.php`.

Comment: it's all about that bass, about that base, which is >>PHP is not a superior lang at the moment.

Comment: yes, general encoding issues can be hard to deal with.  Maybe we should consider to start writing in pure binary code instead ... on a second thought I'm afraid that could give far worse translation problems  ;-) @prosti

Comment: So from what I understand, I have to modify the core for this to work in 4.6.1 ?

Comment: @ChinLeung Please don't modify the core code. For pre WP 4.7, you can use filters as suggested by prosti. It's also always recommended to use the latest versions for security reasons.

Comment: @birgire Yeah I saw his post afterward!

Comment: But still, in my opinion, changing the prefix is just an 'easy way out'. The real way of fixing this once and for all would be allowing the option to **escape** the prefix character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that `NOT LIKE '%%'` is very unique. It can happen only in cases where you search for `-`.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where, $q )
{        
    $where = str_replace( "NOT LIKE '%%'", "LIKE '%-%'", $where);           
    return $where;

}, 10, 2 );

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    's' => '-'

);

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($query->request);
```

The resulting query will be:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%-%')
AND (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%-%')
AND (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%-%'))) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```